# NuGet packages how to know their `using` directive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

A little background. I'm relatively new to the NuGet package manager system, but so far I have installed a few packages.

The question I have regarding NuGet is how do we know how to reference the installed package using the `using` directive?

I know that NuGet packages have a descriptions in the NuGet package manager. However, they don't always show how to import the packages. So I mostly end up Googling for examples of the package that I install to see if there is an example that shows what the `using` directive is to import that package.

Recently I have installed the package `Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform` I have difficulty finding examples online that show where the package resides and how to import it.

Comment: What happens when you put `using Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform;` at the top of a code file?

Comment: To make things clear, you don't "import" anything with using. Using is only shorthand that you don't have to type out whole namespace when using specific type. If you have a code that uses the types inside the NuGet package, then you already know what namespace they are in. If you don't have such code, then why even import the NuGet package?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer but you could try out NuGet Package Explorer. That might be close to what you need.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 and above, when I import a NuGet Package and try to use it in my code, I hover on the Show Potential Fixes suggestion and I import my package there based on the suggestion.

Comment: @SimonWilson when I put that `using` directive it tells me `The type or namespace name 'Selenium' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. VS does give the option correct it to `using OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform;` but that gives the same error.

Comment: You can have a look at https://fuget.org and browse through the content of the package like https://www.fuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform

Comment: Object explorer.

Comment: Hi friend, does CodeCaster's answer help resolve this issue? Or you can add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to share the useful info and workaround you found, just a reminder :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT the problem why I couldn't bring in the namespace is [because the .NET language bindings marked the PhantomJS driver classes are deprecated in 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446115/6410654). 
And thank you very much all the given answers here did help me and resolved my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I put that using directive it tells me The type or namespace
>   name...

All above describes the details about how to know `using` directive, so add some details to clarify why nuget not responsible for it, what in VS responsible for it and what the **Intellisense**(the option ) can do for us.

> NuGet packages how to know their `using` directive?

Nuget in VS is just a `Package Manager`, it won't know the `using` directive.

For the most nuget packages, they contain at least one assembly, when you consume the package, actually you add reference to the assemblies from the package. So it's **equivalent to** that you have some assemblies developed by someone, then you reference them locally(add=>reference=>browse) in your project. So in this situation Nuget won't know how to use the assemblies with `using`...

(Here we **just** talk about the assemblies in package, nuget package has much more advantage from its install.ps1,build content...)

What actually do this in VS for you is [Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019), it's responsible for recognizing your `using` statement in code editor,and help provide quick-info suggestions.(add using namespace,import reference...)

The function you're talking about is `Intellisense`, not `Nuget`, and Intellisense is used to **check** if your `using` directive is correct, it will search whether the namespace you use exists in referenced assemblies, but it will only display wrong(if can't find) or right, it won't tell you how to use the assemblies and what namespace defined in them! That's something you need to go through source code or research the example, like **Vyacheslav** and **CodeCaster** answered.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a NuGet package can contain zero or more assemblies that *can* be added as references to the project in which you install it. So there is no one-on-one relationship between packages and assemblies; neither is there between namespaces and assemblies (an assembly can contain multiple namespaces, or the same namespace can be used by multiple assemblies), so neither is there between package names and the names of the assemblies therein nor the namespaces therein.

So: you have to know what you're doing. There is a reason you chose to install `Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS.Xplatform`. Somebody must have told you to, or you must have read it somewhere that you should do that.

When you do come along a situation where you hear or read *"You should install package `Foo`!"*, then that source should also give you examples for how to use the types contained within those packages. And that's where you should read which namespaces to import in order to do so.

Some libraries also don't need any code to function; they're plugin-like additions to *other* libraries that you should already have in place in order to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Usually nuget packages have a github repository or maybe a website.
Sometimes you can find examples, sometimes you have to go through source code.

I went to their Github repository and found that one of the namespaces they use is: `OpenQA.Selenium`.

You can check their source code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/src).